Map over struct in Polars
In Rust Polars I have a dataframe with columns a and b and a struct MyStruct with fields a and b (with type u64). I want to convert each row of the dataframe into a MyStruct, returning a vector of MyStructs.
In Polars version 0.41.0 the following works:
let foo = df
  .into_struct("bar")
  .iter()
  .map(|row| MyStruct { 
    row[0].try_extract<u64>().unwrap(),
    row[1].try_extract<u64>().unwrap()
  })
  .collect::<Vec<MyStruct>>();

It is also possible to do this by zipping columns together, but I actually have many fields and find this more concise.
In Cargo.toml the Polars dependency is specified as
polars = { version = "0.41.0" , default-features = false, features = ["dtype-struct", "lazy"] }

Now I want to upgrade to the latest version (0.44.2) and I get compilation errors:
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `Option<()>

referring to the row in map. (Also, the argument to into_struct is now PlSmallStr::from_str("bar"))
I have been looking through the release notes since 0.41.0, but I have found no breaking changes mentioning map/iter.

You could also check the edit of this answer

See also this answer. One way to do it is to create an iterator for each column you're interested in, and iterating them in lockstep:
let mut columns = df
    .columns (["a", "b"])?
    .iter()
    .map (|s| s.iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let foo = (0..df.height())
    .map (|_| MyStruct { 
        columns[0].next().unwrap().try_extract<u64>().unwrap(),
        columns[1].next().unwrap().try_extract<u64>().unwrap(),
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

